# Ansible playbook rebooting the server , wait till reboot complete

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ansible, shell-scripting, ansible-playbook

I'm facing a issue while executing shell script with ansible playbook.
**Issue: I'm losing a connection with remote server because shell script is rebooting the server.**

My Ansible playbook

```
- name: Handle reboot
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  
  tasks:
    - name: Execute the script 
      shell: bash testscript.sh
      args:
        chdir: /home/ubuntu
      notify:
        - Wait for server to restart
        
  handlers:
    - name: Wait for server to restart
      local_action:
        module: wait_for
          host={{ inventory_hostname }}
          port=22
          delay=10
        become: false
```

My shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Performing some tasks"
echo "rebooting now"
reboot
echo "reboot completed"
echo "Performing some more tasks"
```

The error I'm getting  while the remote server reboot

```
fatal: [my-ip-address]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to <my-ip-address> closed.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Is it possible to handle a reboot which is done by shell script and wait for connection until the remote server is up again ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the [reboot module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/reboot_module.html)?

Comment: You realize that the commands in your script after `reboot` are never going to be executed?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider , I'm going to install a specific tools which includes this steps. More details about script, It's renaming network interface and assigning specific IP. FYI: We can not change anything in shell script. So i have to think other way to make it work.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider apparently it's executing  , Please check this script for more detail. 

https://github.com/magma/magma/blob/master/lte/gateway/deploy/agw_install_ubuntu.sh

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`wait_for_connection`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_connection_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-wait-for-connection-module) instead.

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Execute the script 
    shell: bash testscript.sh
    args:
      chdir: /home/ubuntu
  - name: wait
    wait_for_connection:
      delay: 10
```

I'd advise to do this in a task, not a handler. The handler is only executed after **all** tasks have been finished, so if you have tasks following the task that executes the reboot they will be tried before the playbook even starts to wait.

Alternatively, use the [reboot module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/reboot_module.html), which does this automatically.

Comment: Definitely , let me try this method.